# Cartopy: importing from new install results in symbol not found in flat namespace '_GEOSCoordSeq_create_r'

Tags: cartopy, geos

I'm setting up a new MacBook and testing the code that I ran on my old Macbook.

One module I need is cartopy. I have installed it using the MacOS instructions detailed here -> https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/installing.html

This all installs no problem. However when I try to import cartopy I hit the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cartopy/__init__.py", line 107, in <module>
    import cartopy.crs  # noqa: E402  module-level imports
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cartopy/crs.py", line 27, in <module>
    import cartopy.trace
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cartopy/trace.cpython-310-darwin.so, 0x0002): symbol not found in flat namespace '_GEOSCoordSeq_create_r'
```

Tried uninstalling proj downgrading to proj7 via homebrew then uninstalling and reinstalling cartopy -> no effect

Tried uninstalling and reinstalling geos via homebrew then uninstalling and reinstalling cartopy -> no effect

Tried uninstalling and reinstalling shapely for versions earlier than 2 then uninstalling and reinstalling cartopy -> no effect

Tried installing cartopy via conda with `conda install -c conda-forge cartopy` -> this results in a package which I can import but which contains none of the cartopy functions and only basic functions from the "string" package.

My current versions are

- cartopy 0.21.0
- shapely 1.8.5.post1
- geopandas 0.11.1
- geos 3.11.0
- proj 9.1.0

Has anyone hit this problem before and solved it?

Sorry for asking but I've been stuck on this for ages.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get cartopy installed via conda but only in the default anaconda environment. That will do but still no idea why I couldn't get it working from  pip using the instructions on the cartopy site